# What's the best way expose a mutable interface over an immutable one?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, properties, readonly

I wonder what's the best practice in C# regarding mutable / immutable interfaces.

I like to work against interfaces only instead of the real objects; remove dependencies and allow for easier testing.

I also usually expose interface that are read-only, which lower errors.
 however this is creating a problem in the actual code when I need to change things on the instance of the object.

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
public interface ISomething
{
    string Name { get; }   
}

public interface IMutableSomething : ISomething
{
    string Name { get; set; }   
}

...

public class ConsumerClass
{
   //Note that I'm working against the interface, not the implementation
   public void DoSomethingOnName(ISomething o)
   {
       var mutableO = (IMutableSomething) o;
       mutableO.Name = "blah";
   }
}
```

Working this way allows me to easily test ConsumerClass and break any dependency between the  ISomething and it's implementation

I know that I could cast the interface to the implementation but this would introduce a dependency on the real implementation.

I could do something like below but I find it ugly and annoying

```
public interface IMutableSomething : ISomething
{
    void SetName(string newName)   
}

or

public interface IMutableSomething // No inheritance, implementation impl. 2 interfaces
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks,

Eric G.

Comment: It seems a little funny to me - you are passing in something with a particular interface (which I read as a "minimum requirement to work correctly"), then casting it to an object that has further requirements on it (must now allow set). It's kind of like setting a goal post, and then when someone reaches it, saying, oh yeah, btw, this isn't the goal post, it's just a half way marker

Comment: In addition, interfaces for the sake of interfaces is not really all that useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your interfaces are fine, but in your consumer code it should look like this:

```
public class ConsumerClass{   
  // Just take IMutableSomething
  public void DoSomethingOnName(IMutableSomething o)   {       
    o.Name = "blah"; 
  }
}
```

The method call is a contract, and as others have said you need to specify the most general type that your `ConsumerClass` can actually use.  You might want to read up on Liskov substitution principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle.

In this case, while IMutableSomething can substitute for ISomething, the inverse is not true.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is something like `var something = Repository.Get(...)` which would return an ISomething then call `ConsumerClass.DoSomething(someThing)` without having to cast as IMutableSomething before the call... This way, I can't inadvertently change the name

Comment: That's not a great idea.  If you need an IMutableSomething, you should have your repository be able to return something of IMutableSomething.  What you're trying to do will just lead to runtime exceptions for your users.  If you don't want to inadvertently change ISomething, then get ISomethings everywhere except for the case where you really do need to change the name.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  That's basically what I'm trying to do w/o having to cast parameters before calling.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the proper use of an interface; the interface is so that you don't care what implementation is, you simply use the defined properties and methods. If you need to 'set' something that has a get only interface, you should not be passing the interface as a parameter.

In this kind of situation, if you MUST go with an interface, define a set method on your interface (or implement the property differently)

```
public interface ISomething
{
    string Name { get; set;}
    void SetName(string newValue);
}

// Choose one of these methods to implement; both is overkill
public class SomethingElse : ISomething
{
     protected string _internalThing = string.Empty;

     public string Name
     {
         get { return _internalThing; }
         set { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
     }

     public void SetName(string newValue)
     {
         throw new InvalidOperationException();
     }
}
```

And then simply have the immutable interfaces do nothing with the value (or throw an exception).

Comment: I"m not sure what the purpose of the code you're suggesting is; it seems like bad design to have a setter that always throws when called, only to have a Set method that does the setting anyway.